# Determinant of the sum of some special matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

$A,B$ are $3\times 3$ matrices. It is known that:

1. $\det(A)=0$
2. $\forall i,j: b_{ij}=1$, where $b_{ij}$ is an element of matrix $B$
3. $\det(A+B)=1$

Find $\det(A+2014B)$

I don't know what to do. I found example in smaller dimensional of matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} 6&3\\4&2\end{bmatrix}$,  but that's all.

Please give me a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C$ be any invertible matrix and $\lambda$ any real (or complex) number.
We can rewrite our $B$ as an [outer product of matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product):

$$B = u \otimes u^T$$
where $u = (1,1,\ldots,1)^T$ is the $n \times 1$ column matrix with all entries $1$. We have:

$$\det(C + \lambda u \otimes u^T) = \det(C(I_n + \lambda C^{-1}u\otimes u^T))
= \det(C)\det(I_n + \lambda C^{-1}u \otimes u^T)$$
Because of the special form of the last expression, it is equal to
$$\det(C) (1 + \text{tr}(\lambda C^{-1}u \otimes u^T))
= \det(C) (1 + \lambda u^T C^{-1}u)$$

Recall when $C$ is invertible, $\det(C) C^{-1} = \text{adj}(C)$ where $\text{adj}(C)$ is the [adjugate matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) of $C$. This implies

$$\det(C + \lambda u\otimes u^T) = \det(C) + \lambda u^T\cdot (\text{adj}(C) u)\tag{*1}$$

Notice the entries of $\text{adj}(C)$ are polynomials in entries of $C$.
Since $(*1)$ is valid for invertible $C$ and the set of invertible matrices are dense in the set of real (or complex) matrices. $(*1)$ is valid even when $C$ is not invertible!

Apply this to our matrix $A$ and set $\lambda$ to $2014$, we get

$$\begin{align}
\det(A+2014B) 
&= \det(A) + 2014u^T\cdot( \text{adj}(A) u)\\
&= -2013\det(A) + 2014(\det(A) + u^T\cdot( \text{adj}(A) u))\\
&= -2013\det(A) + 2014\det(A+B)\\
&= 2014
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** We may (why?) assume that $A=(u,\ v,\ au+bv)$ for some vectors $u,v$ and some scalars $a,b$. Let $w$ be an arbitrary vector. By multilinearity of the determinant function, one can show that
$$
\det(u+w,\ v+w,\ au+bv+w) = (1-a-b)\det(u,v,w)
$$
and therefore the determinant is linear in $w$.

Comment: Wow! It's great!
We can assume A in that form because det(A)=0

Comment: @EvgenyEgorov Merely that $\det(A)=0$ is not enough (consider, e.g. the case when the first two columns are zero but the third is not). You need to  permute the rows and columns of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Possible method of approach:

We can write that $B = xx^T$ where $x = (1,1,1)^T$.  We can then use the [matrix determinant lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) to state
$$
\det(A + 2014B) = \\
\det((A + B) + 2013 xx^T) =\\
(1 + 2013 \,x^T(A+B)^{-1}x) \det(A+B) =\\
1 + 2013 \,x^T(A+B)^{-1}x
$$
I'm not sure if we can get the answer from here (or how to do so).

Comment: Thanks, It's a great lemma, I didn't know it. As answer of question is the one number and here we can see that answer depends on (A+B) matrix, we can guess that exist only one such matrix A o_O

Comment: Not necessarily.  We do know, however, that the way in which $A$ acts on the vector $x = (1,1,1)^T$ is completely determined.

Comment: An example $A$ that will work for us is an appropriate multiple of the matrix
$$
(1,-1,0)(1,-1,0)^T + (0,1,-1)(0,1,-1)^T
$$

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure about that statement about $A$.  But some multiple of the above matrix should work.